# Generate Number with Validating rule in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, auto-generate, validationrules

I have a database in access for institute. there is a [Registers] Table and [Certificates] Table.

[image: Parto.jpg]

I want to give Mark to each of Registers a Mark. I want to set Validation Rule for Each

```
If [Certificates].[Mark]>70
Then UpdateRecord
SetField
CertificateID "GENERATE AutoNumber"
```

My Problem is i cant handle the CertificateID Generate with Macro. i cant use DMAX.
looking for a solution to give CertificateID to only Registers who passed the Course.

Tried "After Update" Macro and "After Insert" macro but still didnt success.

is there any other way to give AutoNumber except "DMax"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i just already found a way but not the best way.

I just added another Table as "Certificates" and renamed current(Certificates) to "Marks".

[Tables and Fields](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wnd285&s=8)

i made a query with Select a "Grade" from Certificates Table and rest from Marks. Whenever i fill a record in Grade table it generate Autonumber for "CertificateID" a new number.

For Validation i set my validation Rule in my form on Grade which i cant fill that field if Marks.Mark is less than 70. ( [Marks].[Mark] < 70)

I know its not a good way.

Still looking for better answer